# About the type check of function return value

Tags: python

Recently I wanted to give my personal project an idea: I want to select different feature branches based on the return type of the function

For example, func() returns an instance of type A, then selects the branch that adapts to A; returns an instance of type B and selects the branch that adapts to B.

It is well known that the class type of an instance can be simply implemented with the instance method, but how to determine the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to do this (Python 3.4+)

```
In[2]: from functools import singledispatch
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: class A:
  ...:     pass
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: class B:
  ...:     pass
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: def func(obj):
  ...:     return branches(obj)
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: @singledispatch
  ...: def branches(arg):
  ...:     print('Not A or B: {}'.format(arg))
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: @branches.register(A)
  ...: def _(arg):
  ...:     print('Handle A objects')
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: @branches.register(B)
  ...: def _(arg):
  ...:     print('Handle B objects')
  ...: 
In[3]: func(A())
Handle A objects
In[4]: func(B())
Handle B objects
In[5]: func('Something Else')
Not A or B: Something Else
```